# "E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer" when I try to send a delete request

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm developing an app that show, save and delete tasks. These tasks are stored on a server. I can post tasks and get tasks from the server but I can't delete because I get this error:

E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8e7e8b8

Retrofit interface:

```
package com.e.databaseapp

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface Service {
    @Headers("user: joan","Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET( "task" )
    fun getListTask() : Call<TaskListContainer>

    @Headers("user: joan")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("task")
    fun saveTask (@Field("task") taskname: String) : Call<Task>

    @Headers("user: joan")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @DELETE("task")
    fun deleteTask (@Field("task") taskname: String) : Call<Void>
}
```

How I'm trying to save the task in the server:

```
fun delete(task: Task) {
        DeleteAsyncTask(taskDao, service).execute(task)
...
}
```

```
private class DeleteAsyncTask(private val taskDao: TaskDao, private val service: Service) :
        AsyncTask<Task, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg tasks: Task?): Void? {
            for (task in tasks) {
                task?.apply {
                    service.deleteTask(this.task).execute()
                    taskDao.deleteTask(task)
                }
            }
            return null
        }
    }
```